# Can I use a logical "or" in a PHP switch statement case?

Tags: php, syntax, switch-statement

Is it possible to use "or" or "and" in a switch case? Here's what I'm after:

```
case 4 || 5:
    echo "Hilo";
    break;
```

Comment: switch ($i) { case $i == 4 || $i == 5 : echo "Hilo"; break; } this worked for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
case 4:
case 5:
       echo "Hilo";
       break;
```

See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php).

EDIT: About the AND case: switch only checks one variable, so this won't work, in this case you can do this:

```
switch ($a) {
  case 4:
    if ($b == 5) {
      echo "Hilo";
    }
    break;
  // Other cases here
}
```

Comment: What about if i want 
case 4 and some other variable c =5 . Can i use AND

Comment: You usage may warrant simply using if/else statements, like `if ( $a==4 && $b==5 ) {}`. It's often more simple and concise.

Comment: Some people recommend against letting cases fall through, such as Douglas Crockford. They can be easy to miss when trying to debug.

Comment: @alex thats generally the recommendation when case 4 does something and case 5 does something but you let 4 fall through. The above example where case 4 does nothing by itself is quite clear and obvious.

Answer (score 4):

The way you achieve this effectively is :

```
CASE 4 :
CASE 5 :           
    echo "Hilo";           
    break;
```

It's called a switch statement with fall through.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) :

"In C and similarly-constructed languages, the lack of break keywords to cause fall through of program execution from one block to the next is used extensively. For example, if n=2, the fourth case statement will produce a match to the control variable. The next line outputs "n is an even number.". Execution continues through the next 3 case statements and to the next line, which outputs "n is a prime number.". The break line after this causes the switch statement to conclude. If the user types in more than one digit, the default block is executed, producing an error message."

Answer (score 3):

No, I believe that will evaluate as (4 || 5) which is always true, but you could say:

```
case 4:
case 5:
    // do something
    break;
```

Answer (score 3):

you could just stack the cases:

```
switch($something) {
   case 4:
   case 5:
       //do something
       break;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
switch($a) {
    case 4 || 5:
        echo 'working';
        break;
}
```