# Logical OR operator in a JavaScript case statement

Tags: jquery, case, logical-operators

I have two jQuery files- one [newForms_jQuery.js] being called on userNewItemForm and adminNewItemForm, another [editForms_jQuery.js] being called on userEditItemForm and adminEditItemForm.

I'd like to combine these two files into one jQuery file and I wanted to use a case statement.

I found out that the syntax would be

```
switch(n)
{
case 1:
  execute code block 1
  break;
case 2:
  execute code block 2
  break;
default:
  code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```

I am getting the name of the file to differentiate btw New and Edit forms and then doing something based on that. My first thought was to use the logical OR in my case, such as:

```
case (url="userNewItemForm.aspx") || (url="adminNewItemForm.aspx"):
//do something
case (url="userEditItemForm.aspx") || (url="adminEditItemForm.aspx"):
//do soemthing else
```

However, then I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806279/429694. So, I revised my script to:

```
switch(url)
{
case "userNewItemForm.aspx": //intentionally left blank to fall through
case "adminNewItemForm.aspx":
// do new record stuff
break;
case "userEditItemForm.aspx": //intentionally left blank to fall through
case "adminEditItemForm.aspx":
//do edit record stuff
break; 
default:
alert(url);
}
```

This seemed to work, however on further testing, I found that the case statements that did not have break; did not fall through as I'd expected. Any advice?

UPDATE1:
Following @jbabey's advice, I revised my script to the following, which I thought solved my problem, however it does not entirely. It seems when I open the url that is in the 2nd part of the OR statement, it doesn't pick up the name, and executes the default case instead.

Here is my current code

```
    function getFileName() 
    {
    url = document.location.href; //gets the full url. URL is global var after function called
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("#") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("#")); //this removes the anchor at the end, if there is one
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("?") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("?")); //this removes the query after the file name, if there is one
    url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length); //this removes everything before the last slash in the path
    return url; //returns filename
    }
$(document).ready(function(){  
     getFileName();
    switch (url)
    {
            case ("eacrfNew_jQuery.aspx" || "newItem_jQuery.aspx"):
              // do new record stuff
            break;
            case ("eacrfEdit_jQuery.aspx" || "editItem_jQuery.aspx"):
              //do edit record stuff 
            break; //close edit record stuff
            default: 
              // which file did it open?    
              alert(url);
    } 
   }); // close doc.ready
```

FINAL UPDATE:

**YOU CANNOT USE LOGICAL OPERATORS IN CASE STATEMENTS**  Instead, you must use if...else  See http://www.naveen.com.au/javascript/jquery/switch-case-in-jquery/319 for details.

```
function getFileName() 
{
url = document.location.href; //gets the full url into global var
return url; //returns filename
}

function clearID()
{
 //clears field values 
}

$(window).load(function(){  
   $(document).ready(function(){  
     getFileName();
     if ((url === "eacrfNew_jQuery.aspx") || (url === "newItem_jQuery.aspx")) {
        // do new record stuff
     } else if ((url === "eacrfEdit_jQuery.aspx") || (url === "editItem_jQuery.aspx")) {
        // do edit record stuff  
     } else {   
       /// default: which file did it open?
       alert(url);
     }
   }); // close doc.ready 
}); // close window.load
```

Comment: What did you expect. What happened?

Comment: @Neal: I was expecting if the URL was userNewItemForm, that it would execute the "new record stuff" below adminNewItemForm

Answer (score 14):

That is why i surround with `{}`

```
switch(url)
{
   case "userNewItemForm.aspx": 
   case "adminNewItemForm.aspx":
   {
      // do new record stuff
      break;
   }
   case "userEditItemForm.aspx": 
   case "adminEditItemForm.aspx":
   {
      // do edit record stuff
      break;
   }
}
```

But there is **no** reason why your current code should not work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the cascading cases, it may make more sense to evaluate your cases as booleans:

```
switch (true) {
    case (bool1 && bool2):
        alert('case 1');
        break;
    case (bool1 || bool2):
        alert('case 2');
        break;
    default:
        alert('default');   
}
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7SDY/1/

Comment: I'm not sure how your fiddle is any different than my third example except that you are just declaring variables and you have a break; after each statement.   If I am missing something then please let me know.

Comment: it is functionally equivalent to your third example, but in my example you evaluate your booleans in the case statement rather than using cascading cases

Comment: first, and most likely unrelated, your URL is a global variable. you should fix that. on the third line, it should be var url = ... and on the 10th line it should be var url = getFileName()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CYkxf/ works as intended, i think you are trying to use switch statements for something that they were not designed for.

Comment: I'd originally intended to make URL a global- see my original post, code sample #2, however, you are correct, now that I know that is incorrect syntax, I will change it to a local.   After additional research online http://www.naveen.com.au/javascript/jquery/switch-case-in-jquery/319, I should not be using a switch statement with logical operators.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6434/discussion-between-jbabey-and-jg100309)

Answer (score 0):

you must have the break in order to get the control flow that you expect every time.

the falling through without break follows the ECMA design.

see [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=191026) for more detailed info